# How do I check whether I'm using two different version of cmake?

Tags: qt, versions, cmake

I've been having some problems with Qt not being able to use the newest version of `cmake`.

I recently upgraded the version using `apt-get`

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.2.2
```

But Qt somehow still uses 2.8, even though it should not be possible.

I guess I am running two versions, so I tried `sudo apt-get purge cmake` , and then reinstalling it, which led me to the same problem.

Is there some way I can test if I have two versions of cmake on my machine, and if I do, how do I remove it the old one?

Could this explain the issue:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep cmake 
cmake                       install
cmake-data                  install
qtcreator-plugin-cmake:amd64            install
ros-indigo-cmake-modules            install
```

And here is the 2.8 version.

```
locate cmake-2.8 | head
/usr/share/cmake-2.8
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Templates
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/completions
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/editors
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/include
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/AddFileDependencies.cmake
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/AutomocInfo.cmake.in
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/BasicConfigVersion-AnyNewerVersion.cmake.in
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/BasicConfigVersion-ExactVersion.cmake.in
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake --debug-output
```

Will show you where is the cmake that it's using.

Comment: Hmm...  output is  https://pastebin.com/ydbSQzuZ

Comment: How do you know it's using 2.8? Have you tried setting cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2.2) in the cmakelists.txt?

Comment: When I change `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)`, it says that it uses 2.8... something..

Answer (score 0):

I have a small tool to find all executables of a given name in my path. You can use this to see if there is more than one cmake in your path. The simple code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

foreach dir ($path)
    if (-x $dir/$1) then
        echo "$dir/$1"
    endif
end
```

Save the above in a file named "every", chmod it to executable. then do "./every cmake".
It should list all the cmake executables in your path.